Salesforce http callout gets 403 (invalid key) with endpoint that works outside the app
I'm trying to access the LinkPreview API (free). It's setup correctly in Remote Site settings, and the api doesn't require any authorization other than including your api key in the URL params. It accepts GET and POST.
I can successfully access the API from Thunder Client (like Postman), and even just in a browser. No problem ever.
However, if I try to access it with my Apex class or exec anon, it gives me an error 403, which the API docs say is Invalid or blank API access key.
I thought Salesforce might be assigning a User/Agent that it didn't like, so I set that with no effect.
Here's the most basic exec anon that fails (the q param is the url for which you want the preview details.) I have used EncodingUtil to assure there are no bad chars in the endpoint.
Http http = new Http();
HttpRequest request = new HttpRequest();
request.setEndpoint('https://api.linkpreview.net?q=www.cnn.com&key=[my key here]');
request.setMethod('GET');
HttpResponse response = http.send(request);
System.debug(' ' + response.getStatus());

In the log generated by this code, there is a full endpoint shown. If I click it, it opens a browser with the result I need, so I know the endpoint works. I know the callout is happening. I've tried the exec anon code from several different orgs (scratch, dev, production) with the same 403 result everywhere.
This is a free API, so there's no "file a support ticket" on their site, but I have reached out to the developer.
Does anyone know what might be subverting the callout when originating from Salesforce?

I heard back from the developer of the API. Somehow my IP address had gotten blacklisted. He removed that and everything works. So, nothing wrong with the code.
